# operational error 1050 Error “Table already exists” in django makemigrations

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

Hi am getting this wherever i try to make changes to my models or trying to migrate
am using mysql and django 1.8.6

operational error 1050 Error “Table 'products_myproducts' already exists” 
just every time i make migrations

```html
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="managers_product",blank=True)
    media = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,
            upload_to=download_media_location,
            storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PROTECTED_ROOT))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(default='',blank=True)
    slug= models.SlugField(blank=True,unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60,decimal_places=2,default=9.99)
    sale_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60,decimal_places=2,default=6.99,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

also fo my products

```html
class MyProducts(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.products.count())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "My Products"
        verbose_name_plural = "My Products"
```

Answer (score 0):

this error causes when you delete migrations directory from your apps and not dropping the database tables.
if data on the database is important, just backup form data and then drop the database tables.
then delete all migrations directory from each app and makemigration then migrate again and import your data.

Comment: should i drop also the default dajango tables

Comment: @Cipher Yes.drop all tables

Comment: when i make migrations says no changes detected

Comment: @Cipher did you delete all migrations folders in each app?

Comment: yes i did there are no migrations folder in all my apps

Comment: @Cipher sorry. add migrations directory and place an empty file named "\_\_init__.py" in each app and try again.so your project will be like this: [each app directoy]/migrations/__init__.py

Comment: Now it is worse with errors which i cant even understand

Comment: @Cipher repeat things that I tell you above again.delete all migrations files except init file and drop database again then makemigrations and migrate. it should solve the problem. if not send a picture from error

Comment: is there a way to attach images in comments

Comment: @Cipher upload in free upload sites and comment link

Comment: any link if you have for the site

Comment: any link if you have for the site